# Spark Scala Column mapping

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In a Spark job implemented in scala, i'm trying to map two structured columns to a json string representation of them.

```
data =  data
 .withColumn("zones",   data("zones").cast(StringType))
 .withColumn("maps", data("maps").cast(StringType))
```

Where "zones" is a list and "maps" a map<string,string>.

I want to be able to have the list of udt serialized as :

```
[{code:'FOO',name:'Foo',type:'BAR',client_code:NULL}]
```

And sensor_values serialized as :

```
{'my_key':'myValue','my_key2':'myValue2'}
```

I can't find how to access my column value to apply a transformation on it.

Comment: probably the easiest way would be to create two `udf` functions for that, and map your values into strings directly.

Comment: great help, I'll post the final code here, thx !

Comment: can you post sample data ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution found :

```
val mapToJSon: Map[String,String] => String = scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(_).toString()
val mapToJSonUDF = udf(mapToJSon)

data =  data
 .withColumn("zones", to_json(data("zones")))
 .withColumn("maps", mapToJSonUDF(data("maps")))
```

It is not the best one I guess since the scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject is a deprecated class now.